# Can anyone explain me following RandomString

Tags: java, jmeter

Can anyone explain me following syntax which is used to create randomstring

```
    ${__time(ddHHMMmmss)}${__javaScript(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1))}
```

Comment: So is this java, or javascript?

Comment: @MarcB It doesn't look like either. `Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1))` is clearly JS, but the surrounding portion is quite weird. Is this JS embedded in a templating language?

Comment: This looks like some JMeter notation. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.floor:

> The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

As per:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/floor

So [__javaScript](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) is a JMeter function that will run :

> Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)

It will give you a number between 1 and 10.

Finally [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) is a JMeter function that will give the current date using [Java format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> ddHHMMmmss

So results could be for today:

- 12220600539
- 12220600531
- 12220600539
- 12220600537
- 122206005310
  ...